# TFS How to compare and choose changes I want from past history

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I was working on a project, and I didn't get the latest version before I submitted my changes, and someone had just submitted some updates to the project. I know I can go to history, right click on the version I want, and choose "Get This Version," but This doesn't let me choose between changes in the two versions. I usually have in the past just copied all of the code I want, but this is very tedious. I know I can click on the files it shows in Changeset Details, and it will show the difference in code, but there's no way to choose the code I want. What would be the best way to get the changes in code that I want?

Comment: Why don't you do a get latest and then fix the merge conflicts you may have?

Answer (score 0):

When several people are working concurrently on a file, you may not be able to ensure that you're always working on the latest version. But you can check in your file no matter what has been modified by others. TFS will provides information and tool to help you **resolve conflicts**.
[image]
[image]
TFS will automaticlly compare your loacl verison with the latest version on server.You can choose which you want to keep.

By default, the window shows only the conflicts caused by the most recent operation you attempted. When the window is in this state, a message appears that begins: Path filter applied. To show all conflicts in your workspace, choose Get All Conflicts. A message that begins with: n Conflict(s) appears. You can also use Refresh, if new conflicts might have occurred. To get more information, reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181432.aspx